# UTF-8 results in questionmarks

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

Writing and reading text in utf-8 results in questionsmarks.

I have a application that exports data from my database into CSV files. These files can then be imported again, acting like a backup. Now I'm having problem with encoding Swedish characters such as "åäö". In my first solution wrote the file using the encoding of the `stringwriter` (see code). When I then looked at the file in notepad ++, it has the `UCS-2 Little Endian encoding` as default.
This file looks fine, all special characters are rendered properly. However, I started to run into issues when importing the file again. As i'm using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`, it of course writes the wrong characters because it is the wrong encoding. A solution here is using `UCS-2 Little Endian` of course. Problem is, I don't want to use it!

So a thing I tried was changing my original encoding when writing to be UTF-8 instead of `result.Encoding`, like this `Encoding.UTF8`. However, when I open the file in excel, åäö is replaced by questions marks.

So my questions is; How do I write and read with UTF-8 encoding with special letters working properly in excel and notepad? Maybe its better to use Unicode?

```
public void ExportAttendees()
        {
            var result = new StringWriter();
            Response.ContentEncoding = result.Encoding; //Encoding.UTF8
        }



public ActionResult ImportAttendees(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

                    var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binData).Replace("\0", "").Replace("\r", ""); //Here I could use something else?

                    //Code omitted
```

Comment: _I don't want to use it!_ explain why please.

Comment: Because it is not default in excel. Import files might be written in other programs, even notepad. Ideally, the import method should support several encodings. Besides Encoding does not have little endian, only Big.

Comment: Don't open the file directly in Excel. In a new workbook, go to "Data" tab, Import, From Text. Then you can specify the encoding and can import UTF-8. Excel-CSV does not open properly when encoded in any Unicode. You can also try opening directly in Open Office or Libre Office.

Comment: Is there really not a better way to do it? I tried this and then saving it and then opened in Notepad++, says ansi even though I specified utf-8

Comment: Yes I used the "Tools" option when saving it, specifying utf-8

Comment: How are you viewing the results?  The ascii data may be correct and what you are using to view results may be wrong.  Using Ascii encoding with remove non printable characters but may remove some needed characters.

Comment: @jdweng I use Notepad++, the encoding is in the lower right corner.

Comment: Use encoding 1257 :             string input = "åäö";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1257").GetBytes(input);
            string output = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1257").GetString(bytes);

Comment: Its a corporate app were people use excel most of the time, so an alternative application like libre office is not really an option for me. I guess they could just use notepad to edit the text file but it would be muuuch better if they could just use excel.

Comment: Finally! @jdweng please write is as answer.

Comment: Why not export into .xlsx files?

Comment: You seem to be confused. *"Maybe it's better to use Unicode."* There is no way to write Unicode without using an encoding, and you are saying this as if UTF-8 and UCS-2 were not Unicode.

Comment: Code page 1257 seems like an odd choice for this, though probably any 8-bit encoding which defines all the character positions will do as long as you completely ignore what the bytes actually represent.